# How to remap the tab key in emacs evil mode to act as escape key?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

This took me way too long to figure out so I'm asking the question and answering it.

In my `.emacs/init.el` I was trying many things:

`(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
    (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "\t") '[???]))`

What's the value I put in there? All I want to do is to have the tab key get me from insert mode to normal mode!

Comment: (Probably a duplicate of a bunch of other questions too.)

Comment: To add to that, this breaks the repeat last action functionality (`.`).
Should I downvote my own question?

Comment: I do agree it is a possible duplicate of the post you link to. I have the lines in that post in my `init.el`. However, as an emacs newbie, I would have liked to see a post like that one specific to rebinding the TAB key. Which I did not find. However, I'm unfamiliar with the etiquette of this SE. Should I not do that? ie. do: There's a post for binding keys X and Y, here's one for keys Z, N.

Comment: Nothing wrong with posing such a question. But it is better if you first search for an existing Q & A that is relevant (saves site maintenance). The point in this case is that whether binding `TAB` or binding `C-f`, the question and answer are essentially the same. In this case, there is the addition of `eval-after-load` (or `with-eval-after-load`), as there is also in the duplicate I found.

Comment: Got it. So if I do something like this and I've seen something similar, but I need an additional detail, should I link to the similar post?

Answer (score 1):

This works on emacs 24.5.1 from the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories:

`(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
    (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'evil-normal-state))`

EDIT: However, this is not recommended as the TAB key is often used for core functionality in many packages. Credit: @Dan for answering [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30181/why-is-my-repeat-last-action-dot-operator-is-not-working)