# Why is my "repeat last action" (dot) operator is not working?

Tags: evil

I'm a vim user moving to emacs evil.

I just added this line to my `.init.el` file and it broke my dot functionality.

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'evil-force-normal-state)
```

Why? I'm not even sure what to search for to start debugging this.

Here's my whole `init.el` file:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

(global-linum-mode 1)

(require 'evil)
(evil-mode t)


;;;; Keymappings                                                                  
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ":") 'evil-repeat-find-char)
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ";") 'evil-ex))
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'evil-force-normal-state))
```

If I don't comment out that line, the `.` in normal mode just deletes the current line as if I'm doing a `dd`. I tried adding stuff to the end of a line then repeating it on a few lines with `.`. All I got was fewer lines!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short version

Switch your code to:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'evil-normal-state)
```

#### Explanatory version

I presume that you're trying to use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key as a
substitute for the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key because the latter is harder
to reach.

As an editorial aside, let me suggest you try remapping the
<kbd>ESC</kbd> key to the <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> key at the system
level, as many Emacs packages use <kbd>TAB</kbd> for core
functionality.

Back to the narrow issue.  In *insert* state, <kbd>ESC</kbd> is
bound by default to `evil-normal-state`, *not*
`evil-force-normal-state` (which is its binding in *normal*
state).  That's an important point because the *latter* aborts the
repeater.  Here's the code that shows you:

```el
(evil-define-command evil-force-normal-state ()
  "Switch to normal state without recording current command."
  :repeat abort             ;; here's the culprit
  :suppress-operator t
  (evil-normal-state))
```

(NB: you can check out the source code with `C-h f evil-force-normal-state` and follow the links.)

Comment: Thanks @Dan! This is very helpful. Trouble is I already have `CAPS LOCK` working as my `CTRL` key... Looks to me like I'll have to get used to a different way. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @meh: if you're on Linux, you can use [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) to have `CAPS LOCK` act as `ESC` when tapped and released, and as `CTRL` when held down.  `Karabinder` used to provide this option for OSX, but recent releases of the latter have apparently gummed up the works.

Comment: @meh: as an aside, `C-[` also sends the escape sequence.